# How to pack bits (efficiently) in CUDA?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, bit-packing

I have an array of bytes where each byte is either 0 or 1. Now I want to pack these values into bits, so that 8 original bytes occupy 1 target byte, with original byte 0 going into bit 0, byte 1 into bit 1, etc.
So far I have the following in the kernel:

```
const uint16_t tid = threadIdx.x;
__shared__ uint8_t packing[cBlockSize];

// ... Computation of the original bytes in packing[tid]
__syncthreads();

if ((tid & 4) == 0)
{
    packing[tid] |= packing[tid | 4] << 4;
}
if ((tid & 6) == 0)
{
    packing[tid] |= packing[tid | 2] << 2;
}
if ((tid & 7) == 0)
{
    pOutput[(tid + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x)>>3] = packing[tid] | (packing[tid | 1] << 1);
}
```

Is this correct and efficient?

Comment: This can't ever work.  That is a memory race. There is not such thing as parallel bit sized transactions in CUDA

Comment: @talonmies, I thought there is no race because threads handling the same byte belong to the same warp.

Comment: Being in the same warp is no guarantee of safety, No two threads can modify the same byte simultaneously without causing a race

Comment: @talonmies, Where are threads modifying the same byte?

Comment: I meant that they handle the same byte sequentially between `if`s, but they don't modify the same byte in parallel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`__ballot()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions) warp-voting function comes quite handy for this.
Assuming that you can redefine `pOutput` to be of `uint32_t` type, and that your block size is a multiple of the warp size (32):

```
unsigned int target = __ballot(packing[tid]);
if (tid % warpSize == 0) {
    pOutput[(tid + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x) / warpSize] = target;
}
```

Strictly speaking, the if conditional isn't even necessary, as all threads of the warp will write the same data to the same address. So a highly optimized version would just be

```
pOutput[(tid + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x) / warpSize] = __ballot(packing[tid]);
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Then I don't need shared memory and `__syncthreads()`.

Comment: As I understand, this doesn't scale to packing 2-bit values? Even though we can use 2 `__ballot` calls, to get lower and higher bits in 2 separate 32-bit variables, then interleaving the bits (e.g. with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490345/interleave-bits-efficiently ) is more expensive on CUDA than the algorithm I gave in the question. For packing 2-bit values, that algorithm would need to write the output inside `if ((tid & 6) == 0)`.

Comment: You can use [shuffle instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-shuffle-functions) to move the data into position before the ballot.

Comment: How is the data stored in each thread? Two bytes, one for each bit? One value where you want to take the lowest two bits?

Comment: @tera, I can store it either way, the conversion is easy. Initially it is 1 value where I want to take lower 2 bits.

Comment: I've put my take on it in a separate answer, so I can format the code.

Comment: maxwell and pascal have [faster shared memory atomics](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/gpu-pro-tip-fast-histograms-using-shared-atomics-maxwell/) so a shared [`atomicOr`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicor) approach should be able to flexibly handle an arbitrary number (or arrangement)  of bits per thread.

Answer (score 1):

For two bits per thread, using `uint2 *pOutput`

```
int lane = tid % warpSize;
uint2 target;
target.x = __ballot(__shfl(packing[tid], lane / 2)                & (lane & 1) + 1));
target.y = __ballot(__shfl(packing[tid], lane / 2 + warpSize / 2) & (lane & 1) + 1));
pOutput[(tid + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x) / warpSize] = target;
```

You'll have to benchmark whether this is still faster than your conventional solution.