# How to interleave two uint32_t values into one uint64_t?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, z-order-curve

If I have two 32-bit values, X and Y, how can I efficiently interleave their bits into one 64-bit value Z, in the order xyxyxyxy...  (Z is a position on a Z-order curve.)

I could iterate over each of the bits in X and Y, setting bits in Z as I go.  This seems inefficient.

Is there a shortcut to interleaving the bits from two values into one large value, which takes less than a hundred CPU instructions?

Comment: Do you have access to [`pdep`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep) or carryless-multiplication?

Comment: C++ version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39490345/555045

Comment: @harold Yes, it looks like pdep would do the job in x86_64.  Is there a similar instruction for ARM64?

Comment: @fadedbee ARM doesn't have an equivalent of pdep as far as I know, but it does have carryless multiplication (polynomial multiply) and a carryless square "spreads" the bits in the way that you need here (but it's part of NEON and not all ARM processors have that)

Comment: @harold Thanks, the C++ answer will work in C too.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490836/129805

Comment: "which takes less than a hundred CPU instructions?" Did you try the obvious - a naive for loop doing this bit by bit? Because I very much doubt you'll get hundreds of CPU instructions then

Comment: @Lundin, I had assumed 32 iterations of a loop with 5-10 instructions inside, totalling over a hundred instructions.  I'll test my assumption in Godbolt later, and post the result.

Comment: gcc with -O3 compiled my function to about 30 instructions, and nielsen's to about 50 but my sse2 function runs slower on my machines.

Comment: @fadedbee Hmm yeah I tried the naive approach and it didn't get optimized well. https://godbolt.org/z/G7zjKEfdG Essentially it just translated the C to assembler, no optimizations were done.

Comment: @Lundin https://godbolt.org/z/6Yz1Yqro5 This naive implementation of `interleave()` has 12 instructions (at -O3) inside a loop which is iterated up to 32 times.  It looks like my assumption was correct, as this could take up to 384 instructions.  Have I missed something?  What did you think that the compiler might do with a naive implementation?

Comment: @fadedbee You would need to specify something like `-march=core-avx2` in addition to `-O3` for gcc to do something interesting with a simple loop. In that case, it can convert the loop into straight-line code with about 100 instructions for the computation of the 2D Morton code. Not great, but better than executing an actual loop. See Godbolt example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Esc87q93n). `expand32_ref()` is the loop-y version.

Comment: can you concatenate two bytes to make a short int and do a table lookup and store the result in less than 25 instructions.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for the explanation, I didn't realise that GCC could be so clever.  Pity it wrecks portability - I'm happy with my 10 year old 2500K PC, but it doesn't have AVX2, and -march=sandybridge doesn't optimise the loop away.

Comment: @Jasen Great idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This C++-answer also applies to C: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490836/11993121

The answer outlines the principle, but does not write out the complete solution. A working implementation is as follows:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t interleave(uint32_t x0, uint32_t y0)
{
    static const uint64_t B[] = {0x0000FFFF0000FFFF, 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF, 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F, 0x3333333333333333, 0x5555555555555555};
    static const unsigned S[] = {16, 8, 4, 2, 1};

    uint64_t x = x0;
    uint64_t y = y0;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]); i++)
    {
        x = (x | (x << S[i])) & B[i];
        y = (y | (y << S[i])) & B[i];
    }
    return x | (y << 1);
}
```

Example of test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBinary64(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t bit = ((uint64_t)1 << 63);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", (x&bit) ? '1' : '0');
        bit = bit >> 1;
    }
}

void printBinary32(uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t bit = ((uint32_t)1 << 31);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", (x&bit) ? '1' : '0');
        bit = bit >> 1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t x = 0x01234567;
    uint32_t y = 0xFEDCBA98;
    printf(" ");
    printBinary32(x);
    printf("\n");
    printBinary32(y);
    printf("\n");
    printBinary64(interleave(x,y));
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Very minor nitpick about the variable names: OP wants X in the odd bits, and Y in the even bits of the interleaved output. This code has X and Y the other way round.

Comment: `x = (x | (x << S[i])) & B[i];`  is less than 10 instructions?  given that S and B  are constants and that the loop can be unrolled that seems  plausable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you having to do this a lot, as in have you got a lot of X's to interleave with a lot Y's? If not, the below is merely for interest only.

If yes, there is an "orthogonal" approach. Say you have 128 X's to interleave with 128 Y's. Start off with 32 128bit vectors, and put the bits for X[0] in the 0'th bit of the 32 vectors. Put the bits for X[1] in the 1'th bit of the vectors, and so on. Do the same for the Y values into another set of 32 128bit vectors. This is effectively transposing the bits in the values to bit columns in a set of vectors. Then, interleaving them is simply a case of indexing alternately an X vector then a Y vector as you re-build the 64bit values from the two sets of vectors.

Admittedly for mere interleaving, the transposition of the ints to a bit column in the array of vectors may be inefficient. But, if there's more bit manipulation to be done later on then a lot of work can be reduced to re-indexing of vectors in an array. Some SIMD units (like Altivec) have vector instructions that can help with the transpositions.

Bitwise logical operations (e.g. AND) can still be done too (1 bit at a time, but for 128 different values at a time), but there's no speed advantage. However in the already-transposed representation there's no disadvantage either. If one's processing is a sequence of bit manipulations and bitwise operations, the bit manipulations are effectively "free", which is where time can be saved.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I'm only having to do this once per packet, in soft realtime.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here is a manually vectorised version which does the bit operations on x and y at the same time using SSE intrinsics. The gcc compiler however, is too clever for me and it optimizes nielsen's scalar function more efficiently somehow.

Anyway, this works but is probably only useful to someone who might want to adapt it to work with a wider vector width to interleave more than one pair of uint32_ts at once.

```
uint64_t interleavesse2(uint32_t x0, uint32_t y0) {
  // Works but is almost 50% slower!! than scalar version when compiled with gcc -O3 -msse2
  // Materially faster than when scalar version compiled with gcc -O2 -msse2
  __m128i mask = _mm_setr_epi32(0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff);
  __m128i z = _mm_setr_epi32(x0, 0, y0, 0);
  z = _mm_and_si128(_mm_or_si128(z, _mm_slli_epi64(z, 16)), mask);
  mask = _mm_setr_epi32(0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff);
  z = _mm_and_si128(_mm_or_si128(z, _mm_slli_epi64(z, 8)), mask);
  mask = _mm_setr_epi32(0xf0f0f0f, 0xf0f0f0f, 0xf0f0f0f, 0xf0f0f0f);
  z = _mm_and_si128(_mm_or_si128(z, _mm_slli_epi64(z, 4)), mask);
  mask = _mm_setr_epi32(0x33333333, 0x33333333, 0x33333333, 0x33333333);
  z = _mm_and_si128(_mm_or_si128(z, _mm_slli_epi64(z, 2)), mask);
  mask = _mm_setr_epi32(0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555);
  z = _mm_and_si128(_mm_or_si128(z, _mm_slli_epi64(z, 1)), mask);
  uint64_t res[2];
  memcpy(res, &z, 16);
  return res[0] | (res[1] << 1);
}
```

Comment: If you're using vector code anyway, why not use _mm_clmulepi64_si128 too?

Comment: @harold That is not part of SSE2. Sticking to SSE2 is good for portability. I'm also not familiar with that instruction. I'm looking at it now...

Comment: OK granted, pure SSE2 is a bit more widely supported, but PCLMULQDQ is from all the way back in 2010 (2013 on the AMD side), it would be weird to see a processor today that doesn't support it

Comment: @harold Same argument goes for popcount and some others, but SSE2 is a fairly standard 'minimum' spec.

Comment: It's a bad standard.